# How to add padding/margin to Lubuntu applcation menu

Tags: lubuntu, customization, appmenu, openbox, lxqt

I've just installed Lubuntu 21.10 and I'm trying to get it more pleasant to look at.

How can I add more padding around the applications in the application menu? Everything is packed in tight. I'd like to pad each item and the menu itself

[image]

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lh7W.png)

Comment: An aim of LXQt is being *light*, so features can be fewer than some of the *heavier* desktops. Editing menus is on the *todo* list (see https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/255 with editing discussed) but many users rarely use the menu anyway. They may use features like `lxqt-runner`  (see https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.3/lxqt-runner.html) or myself I have a panel on the left side of one of my displays were I use the *quicklaunch* feature to create a Ubuntu Unity 7 type of my common apps appear when needed (see https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=quicklaunch)

Comment: If interested in what I describe I do; an *old* pic of this setup exists at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/screenshot-thread/221/2 with some minor discussion...  I'm using that box now (it's *jammy* now & I have extra panels added with it changing as my usage alters over time), but link provided in case it's helpful for explanation (*I even provided the same same links in prior comment I note as in 2019-July thread*)

Comment: @guiverc I did not know about lxqt-runner. Thats a much better experience. You've binded a hotkey to it I suppose. Thanks for the feedback. I like your setup, gave me more to think about.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier; but I don't use `lxqt-runner` myself (*I love my old IBM model M keyboards which lack a super key, so ignore many such features except for some QA-testing*).  If you look at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html you'll note a key is listed to "*Launch lxqt-runner*" (alt F2 pulls it up on my box I note in *Global Actions Manager* but I'd intended to verify what is expected on a normal install before replying.. but still haven't done it thus this vague but still *belated* reply)